# What does 'result[::-1]' mean?

Tags: python, slice

I am just coming cross the following python code which confuses me a bit:

```
 res = self.result[::-1].encode('hex')
```

The encode stuff is pretty clear, it should be represented as hex value. However, what
does this self.result[::-1] mean, especially the colons?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It represents the 'slice' to take from the result. The first element is the starting position, the second is the end (non-inclusive) and the third is the step. An empty value before/after a colon indicates you are either starting from the beginning (`s[:3]`) or extending to the end (`s[3:]`). You can include actual numbers here as well, but leaving them out when possible is more idiomatic.

For instance:

```
In [1]: s = 'abcdefg'
```

Return the slice of the string that starts at the beginning and stops at index position 2:

```
In [2]: s[:3]
Out[2]: 'abc'
```

Return the slice of the string that starts at the third index position and extends to the end:

```
In [3]: s[3:]
Out[3]: 'defg'
```

Return the slice of the string that starts at the end and steps backward one element at a time:

```
In [4]: s[::-1]
Out[4]: 'gfedcba'
```

Return the slice of the string that contains every other element:

```
In [5]: s[::2]
Out[5]: 'aceg'
```

They can all be used in combination with each other as well. Here, we return the slice that returns every other element starting at index position 6 and going to index position 2 (note that `s[:2:-2]` would be more idiomatic, but I picked a weird number of letters :) ):

```
In [6]: s[6:2:-2]
Out[6]: 'ge'
```

The step element determines the elements to return. In your example, the `-1` indicates it will step backwards through the item, one element at a time.

Comment: Great, that was easy to understand. So essentially this is nothing else than list operations that are used here!

Comment: @Patrick You got it :) You'll see it often with strings/lists, and it can even be used for assignment in the case of lists (e.g. `l = ['one', 'two', three']; l[:2] = ['changed']`). Hope it helps!

Comment: if a[::1] means , from 'start' to 'end', step by 1.. then why does a[::-1] mean - from 'end' to 'start' step by -1 ?

Answer (score 2):

That's a common idiom that reverses a list.

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
b = a[::-1]
print b

['d', 'c', 'b', 'a']
```

You can read about 'extended slices' [here](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html).

Comment: Unfortunate choice of words, it does not reverse a list! `a.reverse()`  reverses list `a`. `a[::-1]` returns a reversed copy of `a`.

Comment: While true, my wording was intentional; that distinction may end up being more confusing to a beginner, they are typically better served by being presented with the simplification and working with the abstraction until it does something unexpected.  Variable assignments and mutability are lessons for another day.