# Why is sorted(list, reverse=True) working, but list.reverse() returns None?

Tags: python

This reverse method works (after pasting 2 lists together):

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list_2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
list_3 = list_1 + list_2
print(sorted(list_3, reverse=True))
```

BUT, this doesn't:

```
print (list_3.reverse())
```

The second method gives out `None` on the terminal. I'm confused because my second method is as taught on DataCamp and the first method I learned from another forum. Any ideas?

Comment: That's because `list.reverse()` "Reverse the elements of the list in place." It returns None, it just reverses your original list.

Comment: because it reverses the list in-place and does not return anything.

Comment: IDK what they teach in DataCamp, but they probably meant do `list_3.reverse()` on a separate line and then `print(list_3)` on another line.

Comment: @aaossa thanks both, I think understand, so having print() in front of the method still doesn't allow you to see the list in reverse? As I'm understanding it right now, .reverse() just reverses the elements of the original list and nothing more regardless. Is that right?

Comment: Exactly. Just use `.reverse()` before using `print(my_list)` and you'll see the list is now reversed

Answer (score 3):

This is because the .reverse() method does not return any value, it simply reverses the list it was called from. (list_3 has been reversed)

Try this to print off the list:

```
list_3.reverse()
print(list_3)
```

Comment: See the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and therein the bullet point regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before".

Answer (score 1):

It actually is reversed. If after

```
print(list_3.reverse())
```

you do

```
print(list_3)
```

You'll see that the list is reversed. It's kind of odd when operations that work on a list silently do their thing without returning the modified result, but that is what is happening.

The reason why there are two ways of reversing a list is that if you used list_3 elsewhere such as within a dictionary like so

```
list_3 = [1,2,3]
my_dict = {'test': list_3}
```

Now compare doing the following:

**1)**

```
list_3 = sorted(list_3, reverse=True)
print('list_3 is:', list_3)
print('my_dict is:', my_dict)
```

> my_list3 is: [3, 2, 1] 
> my_dict is: {'test': **[1, 2, 3]**}

vs
**2)**

```
list_3.reverse()
print('list_3 is:', list_3)
print('my_dict is:', my_dict)
```

> my_list3 is: [3, 2, 1] 
> my_dict is: {'test': **[3, 2, 1]**}

With the second method, since you are **modifying the original** list you will modify it anywhere it is used, and so `my_dict['test']` ends up reversed. With the first method **you are receiving a copy** of the reversed list so you don't have to worry about inadvertently causing side affects elsewhere.

P.S. There is a third option. `list3 = reversed(list3)` is a shortened way of doing `list_3 = sorted(list_3, reverse=True)` and is what I normally use.

P.P.S. When you're learning about slicing lists, you may realize that while uglier, there is actually a fourth method of reversing lists too [`list_3 = list_3[::-1]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633635/what-is-the-meaning-of-inta-1-in-python), but since it's not as obvious that you are reversing a list this is more of an interesting tidbit to know then something I would actually use.