# Need help understanding the reverse string solution

Tags: python

How does the range function reverse the string? I understand that range can intake a: start, stop, step - form. I am trying to understand the way it can reverse the string using the negative integers.

Thank you!

```
def reverse_string1(a_string):
    result = ''
    for index in range(len(a_string)-1, - 1, -1):
        result += a_string[index]

    return result
    
string_practice = 'Lucky Doggo!'
print(reverse_string1(string_practice))
```

Comment: Why not write down few iterations of the for loop and track what each variable value is (index and result). I think if you know what range and len does then understanding the rest should be easy! Btw, not a very efficient way to reverse a string ... (read on string immutability)

Comment: Hi. A classic python example is a_string[::-1] to achieve a string reversal. Check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365424/what-does-result-1-mean

Comment: @urban Hi m8, what's the best way to reverse a string, I'm trying to learn as best I can.

Comment: @akhelliuz see above the slice [::-1]

Answer (score 0):

For a string of length `n`, the index of the last character is given by `n - 1`. This adds characters from `a_string` to  `result` in the order `n - 1`, `n - 2`, ... all the way until `0` (the first character of `a_string`), therefore reversing the order.

This can be seen in the arguments of the range: start: `n - 1`, end: `-1` (stops when it reaches -1), step: `-1` (go backwards).

EDIT:
There are also several other simpler ways to reverse strings in python, such as:
`result = "".join(reversed(a_string))`
or
`result = a_string[::-1]`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, this makes a lot of sense. I'm currently trying to learn as best I can.