# Python negative step slice, how, without None, to expresse the equivalent to [::-1]

Tags: python

I've read with interest [Understanding slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing)
and [What does 'result[::-1]' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365424/what-does-result-1-mean)

```
>>> a = 'Python'
# a[start:stop:step]  with start and stop inverted if stem < 1
>>> a[::-1]
'nohtyP'
```

I got that:

```
>>> a[::-1] == a[None:None:-1]
True
```

But I still asking to myself the following question:

Why I cant create with some default `start` `stop` values the equivalent of `a[::-1]` ?

```
>>> a[len(a):0:-1]
'nohty'
>>> a[len(a)+1:0:-1]
'nohty'
>>> a[len(a)+1:-1:-1]
''
```

Can I catch the `P` of Python with explicit indices ?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521798/what-are-the-default-slice-indices-really answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the default slice indices \*really\*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521798/what-are-the-default-slice-indices-really)

Comment: @mkrieger1 Which answer there?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12521981), unfortunately the best parts are in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reverse the string with explicit indices if you use negative indices

```
print(a[-1:-len(a)-1:-1]) # nohtyP
```

Comment: I like `'Python'[~0:~6:-1]`

Comment: @KellyBundy nice, but I think it will be confusing for many people,

Comment: Meh, ever since I realized that `~` gives backwards indexing, it has been quite natural :-)

Comment: Fun fact, just the other day I saw that some guy named Guido once thought [there is no number](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2013-October/023733.html) that achieves this.

Answer (score -2):

I think not because the `stop` value in the slice is not included in the slice.

You are looking for a `stop` value that includes P, in other words includes index 0. However that is not possible due to how python uses negative numbers in slices.

```
a[-1:0:-1] -> 'nohty'
```

We would expect to get P if we go down by one from 0, use -1, but -1 is interpreted as last index, hence the string will be empty.

```
a[-1:-1:-1] -> ''
```

**TL;DR**: nope, not possible